# What is this font being used for these numbers?

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking to identify the font used for the **numbers** in this image. The image comes from Star Trek (the original series) so presumably it's an older font available in the 1960s or was manually produced for the show. And I did try online tools (include WhatTheFont and FontSquirrel) but, because there's just a few digits, I didn't have success.

[image]

Might anyone know the font used, or know one that's similar?

Comment: Hard to tell. Looks kind of similar to [Franklin Gothic Extra Condensed](https://catalog.monotype.com/font/linotype/franklin-gothic/extra-condensed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cosign [Franklin Gothic Extra Condensed](https://archive.org/details/1923AmericanTypeFoundersSpecimenBookCatalogue-Hi-resolution/1923ATFSpecimenBook_pt2/page/n161/mode/2up), although this looks slightly lighter (it could be a slight redraw by the button manufacturer). The text is Univers, incidentally, if you didn't know.